Uids for the folders of Gmail
In c#, .Net integration of gmail emails module into my project i.e. CRM! Can we access the uids of different folders of gmail?
**Is Gmail providing any Uids for the folders? **
I am using IMAP client to integerate gmail into our crm using my gmail account. The emails are being fetched directly from the server after connecting and authenticating. It provides me seperate uids forexample in INBOX, each individual email has its own seperate uid which makes it unique. Is there any way or does google supports and provides seperate uids for knowing the specific folders such as INBOX, [GMAIL]/Drafts, etc. Each folder must have a unique id in my opinion.
NOTE: Fetching all of the folders is not issue here. Those folders has id = null
